# Getting bug "error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix"

Tags: xml, android-layout

I am getting an error "error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix"
My XML file is as seen below.

```
<item xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:title="About Us"   
 anroid:id="@+id/aboutUs"
 android:numericShortcut="1"
 android:alphabeticShortcut="a"/>

<item
 android:title="Preferences"   
 anroid:id="@+id/preferences" />
```

I couldnt solve that problem for a long time. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You've misspelled `android` two places.